# I can't replace the content in the 2nd website base in the user search input in Wordpress Custom Build Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm developing search and replace plugin for Wordpress, I setup a multisite of my Wordpress locally in same account. It  should search page content in the 1ST WEBSITE then target the 2ND WEBSITE for the replacement of keyword that been found in the 1ST WEBSITE.

My problem is that I can't replace the content in the 2ND WEBSITE base in the user search input. Is there something wrong with my code setup?

```
// Hook to load the admin page
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_page_search_admin_page');

// Function to add the admin page
function add_page_search_admin_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Page Search',    // Page Title
        'Page Search',    // Menu Title
        'manage_options',  // Capability
        'page-search',    // Menu Slug
        'page_search_page' // Callback function to display the page
    );
}
```

```
// Function to render the admin page
function page_search_page() {
    $jsonResult = null;
    // Check if the form is submitted
    if (isset($_POST['search_keyword']) && isset($_POST['replace_keyword'])) {
        $search_keyword = sanitize_text_field($_POST['search_keyword']);
        $replace_keyword = sanitize_text_field($_POST['replace_keyword']);
    
        // Call search_keyword_on_website1 with the search and replace keywords
        $search_result = search_keyword_on_website1($search_keyword, $replace_keyword);
    
        if ($search_result) {
            // Update the content on the second website using the post ID where the keyword was found
            update_content_on_website2($search_result['content'], $replace_keyword, $search_result['post_id']);
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the keyword was not found in Website 1's content
            echo 'Keyword not found in the content from Website 1.';
        }
    }
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<h2>Page Search and Replace</h2>';
        echo '<form method="post">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="search_keyword" placeholder="Enter a keyword">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="replace_keyword" placeholder="Enter a replacement keyword">';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Search and Replace">';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';

    // Display the JSON result, if available
    if ($jsonResult) {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<pre>' . $jsonResult . '</pre>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

```
function search_keyword_on_website1($search_keyword, $replace_keyword) {
    // URL for the REST API endpoint of the first website
    $website1_url = 'http://localhost/wordpress-sample-website/wp-json/wp/v2/pages';

    // Define your authentication credentials
    $username = 'admin'; // Replace with your actual username
    $password = 'Administrator123!'; // Replace with your actual password

    // Create the authorization header
    $auth_header = 'Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password);

    // Create the headers array with the authorization header
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization' => $auth_header,
    );

    // Make a GET request with the authorization header
    $website1_response = wp_remote_get($website1_url, array(
        'headers' => $headers,
    ));

    if (is_array($website1_response) && !is_wp_error($website1_response)) {
        // Get the body of the response
        $website1_content = wp_remote_retrieve_body($website1_response);

        // Decode the JSON response into an array
        $pages_data = json_decode($website1_content, true);

        if (is_array($pages_data)) {
            foreach ($pages_data as $page) {
                // Check if the keyword is found in the content of this page
                if (stripos($page['content']['rendered'], $search_keyword) !== false) {
                    // If keyword is found, perform content replacement
                    $content_from_website1 = str_ireplace($search_keyword, $replace_keyword, $page['content']['rendered']);
                    
                    // Return the content and the post ID
                    return array(
                        'content' => $content_from_website1,
                        'post_id' => $page['id']
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Keyword not found in the content or an error occurred
    return false;
}
```

```
function update_content_on_website2($content_from_website1, $replace_keyword, $post_id) {
    // URL for the REST API endpoint of the second website (Website 2)
    $website2_url = 'https://localhost/wordpress-sample-website/website2/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/' . $post_id;

    // Authentication credentials
    $username = 'admin'; // Replace with your actual username
    $password = 'Administrator123!'; // Replace with your actual password

    // Create an array with the content to update
    $content_to_update = array(
        'content' => $content_from_website1,  // Use the content from Website 1
        'status' => 'publish', // Set the status to 'publish'
    );

    // Convert the array to JSON
    $content_json = json_encode($content_to_update);

    // Make a POST request to update the content on Website 2 with basic authentication
    $website2_response = wp_remote_post($website2_url, array(
        'body' => $content_json,
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json', // Use JSON content type
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password)
        )
    ));

    if (is_array($website2_response) && !is_wp_error($website2_response)) {
        echo 'Successfully replace content!!';
        // Content has been successfully replaced in Website 2
        // You can add further error handling or success messages as needed
    } else {
        // Handle errors with the POST request, if any
        echo 'Error updating content on Website 2.';
    }
}

function search_and_replace_content($search_keyword, $replace_keyword) {
    $pages = get_pages();

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $page_content = $page->post_content;

        if (stripos($page_content, $search_keyword) !== false) {
            $updated_content = str_ireplace($search_keyword, $replace_keyword, $page_content);

            // Update the page with the replaced content
            wp_update_post(array(
                'ID' => $page->ID,
                'post_content' => $updated_content,
                'status' => 'publish'
            ));
        }
    }

    // Display a success message or any additional feedback
    echo 'Content replacement completed.';
}
```

I tried fixing but still I can't figure out what's the problem in my code.